# Finding the residue for $f(z) = \frac{1}{(z^2+1)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to show that $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(x^2+1)^2} = \frac{\pi}{4}$$ by finding the residue of $\frac{1}{(z^2+1)^2}$ at $z=i$. I tried using $p(z) = 1$ and $q(z) = (z^2+1)^2$, but I get that $q'(i) = 0$. However, for $q''(i)$, I get $-8 + 4i$. Is it a valid step to differentiate $q(z)$ twice to find the residue? Any suggesting or hints in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $(z^2+1)=(z+i)(z-i)$. Construct a half circle contour from -R to R in the real axis, where $R>1$. Do not differentiate twice. Express your function , $f(z)=\frac{g(z)}{(z-i)^2}$. Then observe that g is holomorphic on a neighborhood of i and is non -zero when evaluated at $i$. Hence, $res(f,i)$ is the first derivative of g evaluated at i.

Comment: I see, I had tried writing it in such form but got my $g(z)$ wrong. I will continue from this point.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ has  a pole of order $2$ at $z_0$ then the residue at $z_0$ is $\lim_{z \to z_0} \frac d  {dz} (z-z_0)^{2}f(z)$. In this case we get $\lim_{z \to i} \frac d {dz} \frac 1 {(z+i)^{2}}=-\frac i  4$.